# PHP Отправка длинного письма на почту

Tags: php, email, sendmail

Есть текст, в котором > 70 символов. При отправке на почту, письмо не доставляется, хотя функция mail() возвращает true. Как можно отправить длинное письмо на почту?

Comment: А сейчас как Вы отправляете ?

Comment: Сейчас отправляю через функцию mail(). Короткие письма отправляются, но длинные нет. Отправляю с локального сервера через smtp.mail.ru, в логе пишет:
2018-06-01 08:14:05  Debug: spam message rejected. Please visit *ссылка на поддержку Mail.ru* ID: 0000000B0001F2D42EB5D6EE.

Comment: Ну как бы информативное сообщение. Пишете видимо какую-то дичь в письме. Ну либо используйте smtp от gmail и будет вам счатье. Если отправляете с линукса, то там почтовик поднимается одной командой, и можно обойтись без smtp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил сменой на PHPMailer.

```
<?php

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;

require "vendor/autoload.php";

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host = "";
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = "";
$mail->Password = "";
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
$mail->Port = 465;

$mail->From = $mail->Username;
$mail->addAddress("");

$mail->isHTML(true);
$mail->Subject = "Тестовое сообщение";
$mail->Body = "Сообщение";
$mail->CharSet = "utf-8";

try {
    if ($mail->send())
        $response = json_encode(["status" => 1], JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    print_r($e->getMessage());
}
```

Comment: Поставьте галочку зелёную, что б был "отвеченым".