# Как отправить результаты теста на почту?

Tags: php, html, email, тестирование

совсем новичок и не никак не могу понять как совместить эти коды что бы отправлять вместо сообщения результат теста?
Мой php код теста:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf8'>
    <title>Управление движением платформы в среде Scratch For Arduino</title>
</head>
<body>
    <!--Объект question для вывода текста задания!-->
    <p id="question">
    У Робоняши левый и правый моторы подключены к 5 и 6 пинам соответственно 
    для управления скоростью вращения. Соберите последовательность блоков программы, 
    которая позволит Робоняше в течении 1 секунды совершить:</p>
    <!--Объект area, содержащий задание!-->
    <div id="area">
    <p class="img"><img src="../images/Rn2.png" height="300">
    <!--Форма ввода ответов!--> 
    <form onSubmit = "return checkform(this)">
        Поворот налево: <input type="text" name="num" id="q1" required>
        Поворот направо: <input type="text" name="num" id="q2" required>
        Проезд прямо: <input type="text" name="num" id="q3" required>
        <!--При щелчке по кнопке ОК запускается скрипт check!-->
        <input type="button" value="Ok" onclick="check()">
    </form></p>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function check() {
            plus=0;//Инициализация счетчика правильных ответов
            //Проверка введенного ответа для первого задания
            if ((document.getElementById("q1").value=='6543')||(document.getElementById("q1").value=='6453')) {
            // Если условие выполняется, то счетчик правильных ответов увеличивается на 1
                plus++;
            }
            if ((document.getElementById("q2").value=='6123')||(document.getElementById("q2").value=='6213')) {
            //Проверка введенного  ответа для  второго задания 
                plus++;
            }
            if ((document.getElementById("q3").value=='6143')||(document.getElementById("q3").value=='6413')) {
            //Проверка введенного ответа для третьего задания 
                plus++;
            }
        //Обработка результатов тестирования
        switch (plus) {
                case 1:
                    mark='УДОВЛЕТВОРИТЕЛЬНО';
                    break;
                case 2:
                    mark='ХОРОШО';
                    break;
                case 3:
                    mark='ОТЛИЧНО';
                    break;                    
                  default:
                    mark='НЕУДОВЛЕТВОРИТЕЛЬНО';
                }
            mess='Количество правильных ответов: ' + plus + "<br>" + "<br>" +'Оценка: ' + mark;
            //Выключение видимости объекта area 
            document.getElementById('area').style.display='none';
            //Вывод сообщения о результатах тестирования
            document.getElementById('question').innerHTML=mess;         
        }
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Мой код пересылки на почту:

```
    <?php


$adminemail="123@gmail.com";


$date=date("d.m.y");  

$time=date("H:i"); 

$backurl="yzz";







$name=$_POST['name']; 

$email=$_POST['email']; 

$msg=$_POST['message']; 




if (!preg_match("|^([a-z0-9_\.\-]{1,20})@([a-z0-9\.\-]{1,20})\.([a-z]{2,4})|is", 
strtolower($email))) 

 { 

  echo "<center>Вернитесь<a 
href='javascript:history.back(1)'><B>назад</B></a>. Вы указали не верные данные!"; 

  } 

 else 

 { 


$msg="Имя:$name E-mail:$email Сообщение:$msg"; 




mail("$adminemail", "$date $time Сообщение от $name", "$msg"); 


$f = fopen("message.txt", "a+"); 

fwrite($f," \n $date $time Сообщение от $name"); 

fwrite($f,"\n $msg "); 

fwrite($f,"\n ---------------"); 

fclose($f); 




print "<script language='Javascript'><!-- 
function reload() {location = \"$backurl\"}; setTimeout('reload()', 6000); 
//--></script> 

$msg

<p>Сообщение отправлено! Подождите, сейчас вы будете перенаправлены на главную страницу...</p>";  
exit; 

 } 

?>php
```

Comment: Вопрос сводится к "как отправить почту PHP"?

Comment: У вас вопрос как отправить, или как составить письмо? Или два в одном?

Comment: Вот пример отправки https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/836197/php-%d0%9e%d1%82%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%8c%d0%bc%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%87%d1%82%d1%83 на so.

Comment: Ну а "составить письмо" - думаю не должно возникнуть проблем.

Comment: Ещё вариант https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/721367/%d0%be%d1%82%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%8c%d0%bc%d0%be-php

Comment: Отправка с вложениями https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/456465/%d0%9e%d1%82%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%8c%d0%bc%d0%b5-php